# keep sidemenu expand every reload

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am facing some situation with sidemenu. I want to make the sidemenu active/open while page load/refresh. The sidemenu is dynamically loaded from database. The problem is when webpage refreshes, all the time after I click on the sidemenu; I need to make the sidemenu stay on active and need solution for this? I tried some javascript from internet but still having the same problem.

here is my code:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar responsive"   >
               <ul  class="nav nav-list" >
                    <li class="#"  >
                        <a  href="#"  class="dropdown-toggle">
                          <span class="menu-text" >
                           <ul class="submenu" >
                           <li class="active" >   //set it active will remain active all the time
                                <span class="menu-text"  >
```

Above is example from my code, Thank you.

script use as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                if (sessionStorage.getItem("activeMenuItemID") != undefined) {
                    $("#submenu  > li > a").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).attr("id") == sessionStorage.getItem("activeMenuItemID")) {
                            expandMenuItem(this);
                        }
                    });
                }

                $('#submenu  > li > a').click(function (elem) {
                    expandMenuItem(this);
                });

            });

            function expandMenuItem(elem) {
                if ($(elem).attr('class') != 'active') {
                    $('#submenu li ul').slideUp();
                    $('#submenu > li > a').removeClass("active");
                    $(elem).addClass("active");
                    $(elem).next().slideToggle();
                    sessionStorage.setItem("activeMenuItemID", $(elem).attr("id"));
                }
            }
```

Comment: try some javascript from internet still remain the same? can you please show what you used. you can use jquery .addClass() and .removeClass() function to  add and remove class from a element in html Refer this https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Try this: whenever any menu gets clicked; add the hash (#) for it in URL and redirect user to that particular page. While loading other page; check is there any # present in URL. If yes then make the side menu active and highlight the corresponding menu.

Comment: better to handle expand/collapse side menu operations using javascript and not by redirecting to a new page showing expanded sidemenu

Comment: @SainPradeep i have update the question please refer thank you

Comment: can you also add you menu complete html? have you debug the java script and find any error?